# How to convert sequence file generated in mahout to text file

Tags: mahout, sequencefile

I have been looking for parser to convert sequence file(.seq) generated to normal text file to get to know intermediate outputs. I am glad to know if anyone come across how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create a SequenceFile Reader in a few lines of codes as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String uri = "path/to/your/sequence/file";
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
    Path path = new Path(uri);

    SequenceFile.Reader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, path, conf);
        Writable key = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(
                    reader.getKeyClass(), conf);
        Writable value = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(
                    reader.getValueClass(), conf);
        long position = reader.getPosition();
        while (reader.next(key, value)) {
                System.out.println("Key: " + key + " value:" + value);
                position = reader.getPosition();
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have sequence data in hdfs in /ex-seqdata/part-000...
so the part-* data are in binary format.
now you can run command hadoop fs -text /ex-seqdata/part*
in command prompt to get the data in human readable format.